# Pandas to JSON Within Groups

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe.  I want to output a json object but nested within `State` first and then `City`.  The `Code`, `Name`, and `Rank` variables all become triplets to make a list of dictionaries.

### MWE

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'State': ['PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'ME', 'ME', 'ME' ],
    'City': ['Philadelphia', 'Philadelphia', 'Philadelphia', 'Philadelphia', 'Scranton', 'Scranton', 'Williamsport', 'Buffalo', 'Buffalo', 'Buffalo', 'Buffalo', 'Albany', 'Albany', 'Portland', 'Portland', 'Ogunquit'],
    'Code': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 10, 20, 30, 40, 30],
    'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'C'],
    'Rank': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3]
})

df
```

I got to here but this was not close to where I want it to be.

```
df.groupby(['State', 'City']).apply(lambda x: x[['Code', 'Name', 'Rank']].to_json(orient='records', indent = 4))
```

### Desired Output

```
[
 {
  "State": "PA",
  "City": "Philadelphia",
  "List": [
   {
    "Code": 10,
    "Name": "A",
    "Rank": 1
   },
   {
    "Code": 20,
    "Name": "B",
    "Rank": 2
   },
   {
    "Code": 30,
    "Name": "C",
    "Rank": 3
   },
   {
    "Code": 40,
    "Name": "D",
    "Rank": 4
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "State": "PA",
  "City": "Scranton",
  "List": [
   {
    "Code": 50,
    "Name": "E",
    "Rank": 5
   },
   {
    "Code": 60,
    "Name": "F",
    "Rank": 6
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "State": "PA",
  "City": "Williamsport",
  "List": [
   {
    "Code": 10,
    "Name": "A",
    "Rank": 1
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "State": "NY",
  "City": "Albany",
  "List": [
   {
    "Code": 10,
    "Name": "A",
    "Rank": 1
   },
   {
    "Code": 20,
    "Name": "B",
    "Rank": 2
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "State": "NY",
  "City": "Buffalo",
  "List": [
   {
    "Code": 20,
    "Name": "B",
    "Rank": 2
   },
   {
    "Code": 30,
    "Name": "C",
    "Rank": 3
   },
   {
    "Code": 40,
    "Name": "D",
    "Rank": 4
   },
   {
    "Code": 50,
    "Name": "E",
    "Rank": 5
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "State": "ME",
  "City": "Portland",
  "List": [
   {
    "Code": 30,
    "Name": "C",
    "Rank": 3
   },
   {
    "Code": 40,
    "Name": "D",
    "Rank": 4
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "State": "ME",
  "City": "Ogunquit",
  "List": [
   {
    "Code": 30,
    "Name": "C",
    "Rank": 3
   }
  ]
 }  
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can try:

```
df["List"] = df[["Code", "Name", "Rank"]].to_dict("records")
grouped = df.groupby(["State", "City"])["List"].apply(list).reset_index()
json_obj = grouped.to_json(orient="records")

>>>json_obj
'[{"State":"ME",
  "City":"Ogunquit",
  "List":[{"Code":30,"Name":"C","Rank":3}]},
 {"State":"ME",
  "City":"Portland",
  "List":[{"Code":30,"Name":"C","Rank":3},
          {"Code":40,"Name":"D","Rank":4}]},
 {"State":"NY",
  "City":"Albany",
  "List":[{"Code":10,"Name":"A","Rank":1},
          {"Code":20,"Name":"B","Rank":2}]},
 {"State":"NY",
  "City":"Buffalo",
  "List":[{"Code":20,"Name":"B","Rank":2},
          {"Code":30,"Name":"C","Rank":3},
          {"Code":40,"Name":"D","Rank":4},
          {"Code":50,"Name":"E","Rank":5}]},
 {"State":"PA",
  "City":"Philadelphia",
  "List":[{"Code":10,"Name":"A","Rank":1},
          {"Code":20,"Name":"B","Rank":2},
          {"Code":30,"Name":"C","Rank":3},
          {"Code":40,"Name":"D","Rank":4}]},
 {"State":"PA",
  "City":"Scranton",
  "List":[{"Code":50,"Name":"E","Rank":5},
          {"Code":60,"Name":"F","Rank":6}]},
 {"State":"PA",
  "City":"Williamsport",
  "List":[{"Code":10,"Name":"A","Rank":1}]}]'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df.groupby(["State", "City"]).apply(
    lambda x: x[["Code", "Name", "Rank"]].to_dict("records")
).reset_index(name="List").to_json(orient="records")
```

Output:

```
[{'State': 'ME',
  'City': 'Ogunquit',
  'List': [{'Code': 30, 'Name': 'C', 'Rank': 3}]},
 {'State': 'ME',
  'City': 'Portland',
  'List': [{'Code': 30, 'Name': 'C', 'Rank': 3},
   {'Code': 40, 'Name': 'D', 'Rank': 4}]},
 {'State': 'NY',
  'City': 'Albany',
  'List': [{'Code': 10, 'Name': 'A', 'Rank': 1},
   {'Code': 20, 'Name': 'B', 'Rank': 2}]},
 {'State': 'NY',
  'City': 'Buffalo',
  'List': [{'Code': 20, 'Name': 'B', 'Rank': 2},
   {'Code': 30, 'Name': 'C', 'Rank': 3},
   {'Code': 40, 'Name': 'D', 'Rank': 4},
   {'Code': 50, 'Name': 'E', 'Rank': 5}]},
 {'State': 'PA',
  'City': 'Philadelphia',
  'List': [{'Code': 10, 'Name': 'A', 'Rank': 1},
   {'Code': 20, 'Name': 'B', 'Rank': 2},
   {'Code': 30, 'Name': 'C', 'Rank': 3},
   {'Code': 40, 'Name': 'D', 'Rank': 4}]},
 {'State': 'PA',
  'City': 'Scranton',
  'List': [{'Code': 50, 'Name': 'E', 'Rank': 5},
   {'Code': 60, 'Name': 'F', 'Rank': 6}]},
 {'State': 'PA',
  'City': 'Williamsport',
  'List': [{'Code': 10, 'Name': 'A', 'Rank': 1}]}]
```